# Descargar archivo pdf mediante url en JSON, C#

Tags: html, c#, jquery, json, entity-framework

tengo una duda en como hacer que descargue un archivo PDF desde una ruta que tengo en JSON, me explico.
Tengo el siguiente modelo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y tengo un boton en HTML de descargar PDF,

```html
<div class="mr-2 form-inline mb-2 form-group">
                            <label for="cliente" class="mr-sm-2">Archivo</label>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Descargar PDF</button>
                        </div>
```

lo que intento hacer es que consuma la url **archivoRuta** que tengo en formato JSON, que es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que quiero saber es como hacer que al momento de oprimir el boton descargar PDF de mi modelo, consuma mi archivoRuta de mi cadena JSON y abra el PDF de la ruta que viene en el JSON

asi es como convierto mi clase ocPedido a un json de esta manera:

```js
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { status = true, mensaje = "PDF procesado en el Pedido: " + ocPedido.customerId, data = ocPedido }); //String
                    return new ContentResult
                    {
                        Content = json,   //Json(new { status = true, mensaje = "PDF procesado en el Pedido: " + ocPedido.customerId, data = ocPedido }),
                        ContentType = "application/json",
                        ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8
                    };
```

cualquier duda estaré al pendiente

Comment: ¿Tienes acceso al códifo fuente de la API o sólo estás creando el frontend?

Comment: solo estoy creando mi frontend, los datos son de un documento PDF que me traigo toda su información respectiva, pero solo estoy ejecutando mi frontend

Comment: ¿Eres el responsable del desarrollo de la API con la que te comunicas?

Comment: @EdgarRojas: Tu pregunta no se entiende y es de muy baja calidad, intenta corregirla por que tiene riesgo de ser cerrada.